# How to call getOrElse + foreach

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Say i have case class with Option[Map[String, String] on it, and i want to iterate throw it.

This code works in Scala 2.13, but in Scala 2.11 build fails.

```
some.getOrElse(None).foreach {
case (key: String, value: String) =>
  if true doSomething
}
```

It says that `Cannot resolve symbol foreach`
How to fix that?

Comment: `some.getOrElse(None)` is equivalent at doing nothing. What should happen if the **Option** is empty? do nothing? Also, are you sure you want a `forach` maybe a `map` or other of the high-level functions may be better?

Comment: Why does some.getOrElse(None) is equivalent at doing nothing? some is not Some() object its my own class. I want to avoid None.get exeption - if Option contains None - return None. Otherwise iterate throw map.

Comment: `getOrElse` get the value or the default, if it is **None** so yeah, it is not actually the same as doing nothing, it is even worse, because you would en with a value of type **Any**. Maybe what you want is `opt.map { map => map.map { case (key, value) =>???}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not default to an empty map?

```
some.getOrElse(Map.empty()).foreach {
case (key: String, value: String) =>
  if true doSomething
}
```

Comment: That is what i asking for. Idk why but in Scala 2.13 i wrote getOrElse(None).foreach and it is works.

Answer (score 1):

It does not compile on 2.13 (or 2.12) so there is clearly an issue with your code.

What I think you are trying to do is this:

```
some.map(_.map {
  case (key: String, value: String) =>
    ???
})
```

This will return `None` if `some` is `None`, otherwise it will call `map` on the `Map` and return the result in `Some(?)`.

Comment: Thank you! It's actually works, but i don't get why does it is not compiles?
Code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Lg29q1OhSJC0hoUdhxh29g